# Best Practice for modelling variations of models

Tags: modeling, texturing, export

I am creating 3D Models of Electrical Network assets (e.g. power poles, transformers etc) for use by a training company.  My goal is to provide the training company with a tool that allows their students to view and interact with different 3D models.  For example, they can view a power pole and "explode" the assembly items".

I have quickly realised there are many variations of power poles. For example, how many cross arms, high voltage and/or low voltage, types of insulators and so on.  So I expect there to be quite a lot of objects that are used in multiple models.

I export the objects in GLTF format to use so I also create textures that I export.

My plan is to create assets so I can reuse objects as much as possible.  For example, power poles have at least one pole and usually one or more cross arms along with the nuts, bolts and washers for holding them in place.  Example below:

[image: sample termination power pole]

In doing this I have been trying to work out what is the best way to do the following:

**Textures**

I initially created an image texture per object, but even when I made these small (1k) the size of my GLTF exports starting to get quite large.
I then combined all the UV Maps into a larger UV atlas (hopefully my terminology is correct).  When I did this, it occurred to me that this might not be the best option for reusability.  So now my thinking is to create UV atlases for common subsets of the models.  E.g. one for cross arms (possibly including the nuts and bolts).  One for polymers (the part in the image above the connects the power line to the pole), and so on.

**Models**
I also wonder if I should build these models in the same Blender file, or have a series of Blender files for each model.  By that I mean have my underlying asset file with all the objects I want as assets, and separate Blender files for each different assembly.

**Viewing Engine**
Lastly, I present the models using 3D Vista (an application for 360 virtual tours that now supports 3D Models).  This is how I first got started in 3D Modelling and learning Blender.  So I am also wondering if there might be a "better" application for achieving my goal than 3D Vista.

I don't expect that there is a single definitive answer to these questions, and I expect I might come up with some more questions as I work through this.  However, I am sure others out there might have had similar experiences and I would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sound like an "asset pack" or "kitbashing". I guess it's a good idea to keep as much as possible procedural (textures, Geometry Nodes) and use modifiers where possible. For the export, finalize the models and bake the textures or use seamless textures. Maybe these videos are helpful https://youtu.be/Cdh2IZmW5ZQ?feature=shared and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxOmflsO04A&list=PLn3ukorJv4vu4aF4bbDA9GeX_puW7sKdE

Comment: Thank you.  The youtube links were helpful.